# Converting a DNA strand to a regular expression

Tags: python, bioinformatics, python-re

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import re

with open("link_allenz.txt") as f:
    s = f.read()


baseDict={'A':'A','C': 'C','T':'T','G':'G','R':'[GA]','Y':'[CT]',
          'M':'[AC]','K':'[GT]','S':'[GC]','W':'[AT]',
          'B':'[CGT]','D':'[ACT]','V':'[ACG]','N':'[ACGT]',',':'|'}

pat1=r'<1>(.*)\n(?:.*\n){3}<5>(.*)\n'
re1=re.compile(pat1)
e2r_dict=dict(re1.findall(s))

def make_seq_2_re(strand):
    while True:
        try:
            x=e2r_dict[strand]
            x_split=list(x)
            print(x_split)
            for base in x_split:
                if baseDict.get(base):
                    x_split[x_split.index(base)]=baseDict[base]
                else:
                    x_split.remove(base)
            y=''.join(x_split)
            if len(y)>0:
                return(y)
            else:
                print("No known strand for "+strand+"!")
            break
        except KeyError:
            print("Was there a spelling error?")
            pass
```

For my class project this is supposed to read a file full of DNA strands and convert the one I tell it to into a regular expression. For some reason it doesn't always convert every letter it needs to. For instance, if it's supposed to convert GACNNNN^NNGTC, it will output GAC[ACGT][ACGT][ACGT][ACGT][ACGT]**N**GTC, ignoring that last N. How do I change this?

Comment: What’s the input format? Something like `<3>GACNNNN<5>`, I assume? What’s the `^` in the input supposed to do? The code you’ve shown also never calls `make_seq_2_re`. How are you calling it? — Please show your *complete* code.

Comment: The `^` is to be removed from the strand and ignored. As for how I call it I simply put `print("\nThe corresponding strand of DNA for this enzyme is: \n\n"+ make_seq_2_re(enzInput))`, where `enzInput` simply asks for the enzyme.

Comment: `<1>AasI
<2>DrdI
<3>Arthrobacter aurescens RFL3
<4>V. Butkus
<5>GACNNNN^NNGTC
<6>
<7>B
<8>1596`

This is the format of each enzyme in the.txt. The enzyme name is near <1> and the strand is near <5>, explaining `pat1`.

Answer (score 1):

You’re modifying `x_split` while iterating over it. This fundamentally doesn’t work. Instead, the solution is to generate a new sequence as you iterate over the input.

There are multiple other issues with this code.

1. What does `while True:` do? It seems unnecessary, and you *always* break after one iteration. You can remove it entirely.
2. Your `try` block means that if the user calls the function with a wrong key, they get a message instead of an error. Creating a readable message is fine, but swallowing an error is *not*. Raise a custom error instead.
3. The `try` block is too large: it should only encompass the `e2_dict` subsetting, not the entire function. Making it smaller makes it clearer where the error can occur, and makes the code more readable.
4. `x_split=list(x)` is unnecessary: strings are sequences, you can iterate over them same as if they were lists.
5. `x_split.index(base)` does the wrong thing: it returns the *first* index of `base` in `x_split`. Consider what happens when you have the input `GAA`, and you’re at the last base: `x_split.index('A')` will return 1, not 2 (the correct index). You cannot use `index` here. If you need the index while iterating over a sequence, use `for i, base in enumerate(x_split)`. However, we *don’t* actually need this in the corrected code, see below.
6. The combination `baseDict.get(base)` … `baseDict[base]` performs one redundant lookup. Ideally we want to avoid such unnecessary work.
7. `if len(y)>0:` is a bit odd: this condition will only be `False` if `e2r_dict[strand]` exists but is either empty or contains only invalid symbols (e.g. `^^`). Is this an actually occurring case? If so, the error message should be improved. And, again, don’t print error messages. *Raise errors*. We also don’t  need the `else` case if we invert the condition.
8. The name `strand` is odd: it seems to refer to something other than a stand of DNA; I don’t know your exact domain so maybe this is the correct term but I’ve never heard it refer to anything other than DNA strands in the context of sequence analysis.
9. Similarly, names like `pat1`, `re1`, `baseDict`, `x` and `y` are not good names, they either don’t give any information about their purpose at all (`x`, `y`) or they give irrelevant information (what’s `1` in `re1`? what is `baseDict` *for*?).

   Choosing good names is important, as it drastically increases readability. `make_seq_2_re` is better, but can still be improved: `make` is usually too generic to be useful in names (though there are exceptions), and such names are usually phrased as “make A from B”, not “make B to A”, to conform with English grammar.
10. Familiarise yourself with [the official Python style guide, PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). In particular, prefer `snake_case` to `mixedCase` and put consistent spaces around your operators.

Taking all this into account, I’d write the function like this, for instance:

```
def seq_re(name):
    try:
        seq = e2r_dict[name]
    except KeyError:
        raise KeyError(f'No sequence found for {name}')

    re = ''
    for base in seq:
        pattern = base_pattern_table.get(base)
        if pattern:
            re += pattern

    if not re:
        raise RuntimeError(f'sequence for {name} was invalid')

    return re
```

However, Pythonists love list comprehension, and building up a sequence iteratively from an empty list is seen as something of an anti-pattern. So I would be tempted to rewrite that part:

```
def seq_re(name):
    try:
        seq = e2r_dict[name]
    except KeyError:
        raise KeyError(f'No sequence found for {name}')

    re = ''.join([pattern for base in seq
        if (pattern := base_pattern_table.get(base))])

    if not re:
        raise RuntimeError(f'sequence for {name} was invalid')

    return re
```

Note that, since this uses the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html), it requires a very recent version of Python (≥ 3.8). I generally urge caution against overuse of this operator. But I think it’s appropriate in this case.

Comment: Thanks so much! As you can probably guess, I am very much a beginner at Python. I might have a few other questions as I progress through this project, we'll see.